# Typescript KnockoutJS Click binding bug

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

Starting out with Typescript and KnockoutJS together and I've hit on a bug I can't reason out yet.
HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: Items()">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item"
           data-bind="text:Name, click: $parent.SetCurrent">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript as follows:

```
/// <reference path="knockout.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

module ViewModels {
    export class ItemViewModel {
        public Name: KnockoutObservable<string>;

        constructor(name: string) {
            this.Name = ko.observable(name);
        }//constructor
    }

    export class MainViewModel {
        public SelectedItem: KnockoutObservable<ItemViewModel>;
        public Items: KnockoutComputed<Array<ItemViewModel>>;

        constructor() {
            this.SelectedItem = ko.observable<ItemViewModel>();
            this.Items = ko.computed({
                owner: this,
                read: () => {
                    return this.get_items();
                }
            });
        }

        //TODO: replace this with knockout.mapping plugin transforms
        private convert_from_model(items_model) {
            var arr = new Array<ItemViewModel>();
            var owner = this;
            items_model.forEach(function (item) {
                var d = new ItemViewModel(item.name);
                arr.push(d);
            });
            return arr;
        }

        private get_items(): Array<ItemViewModel> {
            var items = [{ "name": "AAAA" }, { "name": "BBBB" }, { "name": "CCCC" }, { "name": "DDDD" }];

            var items_c = this.convert_from_model(items);
            return items_c;
        }

        public SetCurrent(item: ItemViewModel) {
            this.SelectedItem(item);
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModels.MainViewModel());
};
```

The problem is setting the current item on click event.

```
public SetCurrent(item: ItemViewModel) {
    this.SelectedItem(item);
}
```

click event correctly calls **SetCurrent**, but the 'this' is of type **ItemViewModel** not **MainViewModel** as it should be. Am I missing something obvious?

Here's a [VS2013 solution](https://github.com/kip9000/TypeScriptHTMLApp1) with everything to repro the problem.

Thanks

Comment: helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
click: $parent.SetCurrent
```

Knockout always invokes event handlers with `this` set to the *current* view model. This particular binding means (to Knockout) "Invoke `$parent.SetCurrent` with *the current view model* as `this`".

The simplest fix is to use an *arrow function* to always have the correct `this`

```
    // Change the definition of SetCurrent like so:
    public SetCurrent = (item: ItemViewModel) => {
        this.SelectedItem(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is a common binding bug.
Solution was to force binding with

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item"
           data-bind="text:Name, click: $parent.SetCurrent.bind($parent)">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either capture `this` in the closure for SetCurrent or bind `$parent.SetCurrent` to `$parent`. For the former, Typescript provides a nice way to do this with lambdas, but note that SetCurrent will no longer be defined on MainViewModel's prototype:

```
SetCurrent = (item: ItemViewModel) => {
    this.SelectedItem(item);
}
```

For the latter, change the click binding to `$parent.SetCurrent.bind($parent)`